# Can I display top charts in my app using album artwork from iTunes?

Tags: itunes, album, copyright

I have used this [iTunes API](https://rss.itunes.apple.com/en-us) to display the top charts in my app but recently I received an email from Apple about the complaints that [Recording Industry Association of America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recording_Industry_Association_of_America)  (RIAA) want to take my app down because of the infringement of album cover artwork. I have seen a lot of others apps are showing the artwork, like:

- [iMusic](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imusic-mp3-music-player-playlist-manager-unlimited/id1061546531?mt=8)
- [Music Player & Unlimited Songs 4+](https://itunes.apple.com/my/app/id1034709839)

and many more.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that what Apple's email says is going to be the most important thing here.

For example are they asking you to remove the artwork? Or are they just trying to inform you that they're getting complaints?

My thinking would be that since you're publishing an app on Apple's App Store that you'd have to take their email as a strong indicator of what you can do (or need to do).

As a registered Developer, you can also call [Apple Developer Program Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/) in your country for clarification/guidance.

Finally, if Apple wants you to stop showing the artwork, it may be worth mentioning the other apps to them. However, it is entirely possible that Apple has also written to their developers too asking them to take the same action.

Comment: @BOBOKING Okay, in that case I suggest you call [Apple Developer Program Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone/) and tell them about your email and ask what action, if any, you need to take? At least that's what I would do. It's the only way to get some certainty as to what Apple requires (if anything) of you. If Apple doesn't require anything of you, then it's a judgement call whether you want to pursue it further (e.g. by contacting RIAA or seeking legal advice). Beyond that there's really nothing more anyone here can do for you, beyond providing a personal opinion.

Comment: Ah, they've removed the phone numbers! :( I'll have to check to see if they've just been moved elsewhere. In any case, if it was me I would go with **Feedback and Other Topics > My issue is not listed**. The only other option I'd also consider is **Development and Technical > Other Development or Technical Questions**.

Answer (score 0):

No unless you license that artwork. Contact the owner of the art to get a license.

You can’t include fonts or music or text you didn’t make and the same with art.

If you’re not sure about the law in your country start with getting a lawyer to read through the contract you signed as a developer and then work through the Apple legal page on what iTunes and API licenses mean.

Worse, you’re likely running afoul of specific app review guidelines.

- 3.2 Business Models
- 4.5 Apple Sites and Services
- 5.2 Intellectual Property

But maybe a small change is all Apple is asking. Why not make the change they asked and resubmit for review?